# Stop list item onclick event firing when when scrolling

Tags: html, css, cordova, dom-events

I have a scrolling unordered list, this is part of a html5 app on a touchscreen device. My problem is when the user is scrolling then release there finger from the list it clicks the element the user used to scroll. Is there any way to change the `onclick` behavior so it only fires if the user has clicked and not scrolled?

```
<ul class="search">
    <a onclick="event()"><li>Name</li></a>
    <a onclick="event()"><li>Name</li></a>
    <a onclick="event()"><li>Name</li></a>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated I can't find any documentation on this online.

Comment: check if scroll position has changed between touch and when no touch, then you can preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

Don't think click think mousedown mousemove mouseup only a down up triggers your click. You'll want a minimum amount of move allowed before trigger your click.